# Script to get generated excel file through button

Tags: python, excel, download

So i have a website and everyday it generates one excel file with statistics.
In order to download the file i have to hit a button and it returns the file(generated through form call).

Is there any way to do it automatically with python or another scripting language?
I want to download the excel files for 2 years and i don't want to click every time the download button (after a change the address from calendar or url)

I tried with web scraping but nothing worked for me.
I do not know the exact urls for every day to do it.

The website is in Drupal if i understand correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.
You can use `requests` module to send POST/GET request which could be the same message when you click the button. Here is instruction for you. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

2.
You can use  `Selenium` to help you, which is a tool for you to simulate a browser and allows you control a real web browser at the same time. Here is instruction for you. http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

3.
You can use `urllib/urllib2` to simulate this click operation as well. But it's not so ease of use.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: i can call the form from chrome console with: document.forms[2].submit();  but do you know how i can redirect and keep the console executing the submit call?

Comment: @Saksoo I thought you would like to click a button in your question, would you? Why is here a form issue?

Comment: yeah its a button that submits a form. It works when i call it from chrome console with document.forms[2].submit(); but i want to call it for a lot of sites with a loop. Is that possible? I want a loop that redirects in a new site calls the forms and again the same for all sites

Comment: @Saksoo Yes, I think so. If you can do it in parallel using threading, I think it would be faster. If my answer helps, please accept it. :)